# single and muti check through checkbox with respect to select option

Tags: jquery

I have a `select` followed by a checkbox. The select box options are `single-product` and `multi-product`. If I choose `single-product` then I want to only check a single checkbox at a time and if I choose `multi-product` then I want to check multiple values at a time.

Comment: The requirements are clear. Where is your code, and a description of the issues you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#product-type").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).val() == "single-product"){
      $(".product-wrapper").addClass("single").removeClass("multiple");
      
      // deselect if there are seletect multiple
      let selected = $(".product-wrapper .product:checked");
      selected = selected.not(selected.first());
      selected.prop("checked", false);
    }
    else{
      $(".product-wrapper").removeClass("single").addClass("multiple");
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on("change", ".product-wrapper.single .product", function(){
      let selected = $(".product-wrapper .product:checked").not(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
  
  // initialize the class of the .product-wrapper
  $("#product-type").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="product-type">
    <option value="single-product">Single product</option>
    <option vlaue="multiple-products">Multiple products</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="product-wrapper">
  <div>
    <label for="product-1">Product 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="product-1" id="product-1" class="product" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="product-2">Product 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="product-2" id="product-2" class="product" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="product-3">Product 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="product-3" id="product-3" class="product" />
  </div>
</div>
```